# PRAW limiting Reddit bot per thread

Tags: python, limit, bots, reddit, praw

I created a Reddit bot with PRAW which automatically responds with a message when it finds key words. The issue is that people are spamming the key words now and one of the mods told me to limit the bot to reply to one comment per thread. I'm not a master programmer but I believe the bot only scans the 25 most recent comments of all the threads combined. It does not care about individual threads currently. Any ideas on how to limit the bot to only reply to one comment per thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to your problem. Keeping a database with threads that you already responded would be most clean, or in this case since it's very little information, you could just save thread ids to file.

This however would be problematic if this database/file would get lost, or bot post would be removed manually or whole lot of other scenarios. So probably best approach now is to do it dynamically and if it slows bot down later on you might consider adding above methods as lookup for faster responses.

What I'm talking about now is everytime you check comment, you should get `submission_id` and scan all comments to make sure no bot reply has ben added yet (or ceratian threshold has not been passed).

```
def scan():
    for c in reddit_client.get_comments('chosen_subreddit'):
        if keyword not in c.body.lower(): #check main requirement
            continue
        if c.author == None: #comment deleted
            continue
        if c.author.name == bot_name: #don't bother with comments made by bot
            continue
        answer(c,c.link_id[3:])

def answer(comment, sub_id)
    sub = reddit_client.get_submission(submission_id=sub_id)
    sub.replace_more_comments(limit=None,threshold=0)
    flat_comments = praw.helpers.flatten_tree(sub.comments)
    if len([com for com in flat_comments if com.author != None and com.author.name.lower() == bot_name.lower()]) > 0:
        return False
    #here you can prepare response and do other stuff
    #....
    #....
    comment.reply(prepared_response)
    return True
```